# Laravel 5 authentication: Change authentication table name user to other

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

i want to change user authentication table 'User' To 'Admin'.
i have changed model name and table name in  `cofig/auth.php` file but its not working please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too little information/code to help you out here.

Answer (score 1):

To change the table name of a model in Laravel 5 you simply have to add a

```
protected $table = "table_name";
```

to your model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

Comment: thank you so much for help ..i have changed table name in User model but no luck its not getting logged in. :(